# How to access the root account home folder?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, root, guest-session

I want to access the root account home folder to delete some files because when I logging to Ubuntu 12.04 it says that no enough memory to write after typing the password. But i can log into guest user account. To get the memory how can i delete the file from guest user account? ( I have the root password because I'm the root).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not access root from guest account. Rather you can try to login to a virtual console. For that you need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> at your login screen.

At virtual console to login into the CLI enter your username and password. To move to root accounts home folder use the following commands,

```
$ sudo -i
```

Check the present directory using the command

```
$ pwd
/root
```

Now delete at your wish using the following command,

```
rm -ri <folder>  # To delete folder
rm -i <file>  # To delete file
```